# You Tube Search List Api searches on title or description or tag field?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As mentioned in the doc, search list api returns a collection of search results that match the query parameters specified in the API request. By default, a search result set identifies matching video, channel, and playlist resources, is this searching done on title, description and tag fields or only on title or tag field of the video, channel and playlist resource?

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use `allintitle` operator to search youtube videos on title
so your query will look like

```
allintitle:"How to dance"
```

You can read more about this [here](https://www.labnol.org/internet/youtube-search/19261/) and [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/search-youtube-pro-google-advanced-operators/)

You can do the same using youtube API

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) :

> Required parameters:
>
> `part`
>
> string
>
> The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more
>   search resource properties that the API response will include. Set the
>   parameter value to snippet.

You can try it in [YouTube Search List API Try It](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&_h=4&). Remember to be authorized first before you execute it.

The other parameters like you mentioned earlier: title can be replaced with the `q` parameter to be specific with your search. The q parameter can be found in the [Search For Files document](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

> You can search or filter files with the files.list method of the Drive
>   API. These methods accept the q parameter which is a search query
>   combining one or more search clauses. Each search clause is made up of
>   three parts.

Unfortunately, you cannot select where the `q` will look into e.g. title, tag, description.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The answer does not address the question and includes links to the unrelated Drive API. The correct link is https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#q